# Deleting same number of records from SQL Server database takes either 0.2 sec or 30 sec

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I am deleting ~5000 records from a table.  While I was testing performance with the same data I have found that the deletion either takes 1 sec or 31 sec.

The test database is confidential so can not share it here.

I have already tried to separate the load and only delete 1000 record at a time but I still experience the deviation.

How should I continue my investigation? What could be the reason for the performance difference?

The query is simple, something like: `delete from PART where INVOICE_ID = 64225`

Comment: Please post the query and the execution plan of the query.

Comment: When it takes 1 and when 31 seconds? Is it reproducible or unpredictable?

Comment: The only pattern I have noticed is that it changes after 1-4 executions (e.g. slow once and then fast 4 times and vice versa)

Comment: Are there any other processes, accessing same database or same server? In SQL monitoring tools, what other activity you see, what kind of waits you see (network IO, disk IO)? Does query performance depend on records content - some triggers or foreign keys with cascading deletes present?

Comment: @TT in what format can I post the execution plan? I have the XML from the profiler or the sqlplan file

Comment: @Arvo no, tested on single machine, no other process accessing the server.  Also tested on other machine, same results. Each test deletes the same data. There are no cascading deletes and triggers.

Comment: In SSMS, click the `Include Actual Execution Plan` button before executing. When you execute it there's an extra tab with the execution plan. Take a screenshot of it and post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE clause uses a lot of system and transaction log resources and thats why it can take a lot of time. If possible try to TRUNCATE the table instead.

Comment: TRUNCATE is not an option (added query to question). I understand that delete is expensive but what's strange that the same delete is either cheap (1 sec) or expensive (30 sec).

Answer (score 0):

When you run the DELETE for the first time perhaps the data wasn't in the buffer pool so had to be read off storage, the second time you run it will be in storage. Other factors will include if the checkpoint process is running your changed pages off to storage. Post your query plan ->

```
set statistics xml on

select * from sys.objects

set statistics xml off
```

Answer (score 0):

Argh! After having a closer look at the execution plan I have noticed that one index was missing. After adding the index all executions are running fast. Note that after this I have removed the index to test if the problem comes back. The performance deviations re appeared.